# What is the use of *-doc packages?

Tags: package-management, documentation

I was installing some programs, and every program has a `XXX-doc` package. I suppose it's for documentation, maybe even for man pages? Because I get a documentation online, thus in that case may I remove all -`doc` packages? I only need basic man pages, not the whole documentation, so what they really should consist of?

E.g: `vim-doc` consist only from .html files (checked using `dpkg`), so man page isn't there I think, so what's the use of doc package?

Is it safe to: `sudo apt-get purge (or remove) .*-doc`?

Comment: Why? I doubt you will save tremendous space by doing so. Admittedly most of the documentation and it's location is fairly obscure.

Comment: @haziz texlive docs are 2.5 GB, mostly PDFs that have never been opened.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you noticed, doc packages are not for basic man/info pages. They contain extended documentation,  usually in the form of HTML pages.  So Generally it's be safe to remove any installed doc packages. just make sure you don't over-remove packages, which is especially easy with `*`. Additionally regex is somewhat difficult from `apt-get`, it does not seem to use the standard POSIX/Extended POSIX style. I would actually do something like this.

```
dpkg -l | awk ' { print $2 } ' | grep '\-doc$'
```

If you approve of that list displayed, you can then attempt to purge them like this,

```
sudo apt-get purge `dpkg -l | awk ' { print $2 } ' | grep '\-doc$'`
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing though; extended documentation is often in packages not called `-doc`, and if I recall a few `-doc` packages *do* contain man pages.

Comment: Unfortunately consistency is not always 100%, regarding community created software/packages.  Obviously this has dramatically improved over the years.  I did consider the possibility, which is why I could only speak '... Generally ...'.  Additionally I did emphasize the importance of review.

Comment: The documentation maintained by the Ubuntu documentation team is in ubuntu-docs or depending on your flavor (x)(k) etc...