# Undo remove documentation from Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, restore, documentation

I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/401144/65529) to the question of removing Ubuntu documentation to save space. While the method worked, it has rendered my system somewhat broken. Every now and then when I install some package, it depends on some folder in the documentation existing. Two such apps are:

1. Virtual Box (error during run -- had to create /usr/share/doc/virtualbox)
2. PostgreSQL (error during installation -- had to create /usr/share/man/man7)

*EDIT*

It took a lot of digging (around 2 days) to find solution to 1.
Unfortunately, there was no way to find out which directory was the issue, or even that the existence of the directory was the issue. Fortunately, after 2 days, just before I was about to do a clean install, I came across [this post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=52865) that hinted that removing the documentation *could be* the problem.

So the solution is not just to "recreate the folder", as one of the comment says, but to find out *which folder(s) to recreate*, which is not so easy.

2 was easier due to the error printed on console.

For now I would like to get my system back to the "unbroken" stage without having to do a complete reinstall. What is the best way to get documentation back?

Comment: A comment under the accepted answer __says you should manually recreate__ those folders removed, did you try that?

Comment: Yes I did try that. In fact that's how I got the above two to work. I'm talking about the general case. In `rm -rf /usr/share/man/* /usr/share/groff/* /usr/share/info/*`, we don't really know what folders were deleted, unless you are a Linux guru. I have edited the question.

Comment: Boy, just looked at those folders and there's a lot that got removed especially in the `/usr/share/info/*`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to regenerate any package-provided file, including documentation, is to reinstall the package.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall package_name
```

However, sometimes documentation is provided by a different package:

```
dpkg -L package_name        // List of files installed by the package
apt depends package_name    // Other dependency packages, including doc packages
```

If you are unsure which package provided a file, it's easy to look up:

```
dpkg -S /path/to/file_name
```

And one tip: The package manager (apt/dpkg) cares about the *presence* of a file. **Never** manually remove a file placed by apt/dpkg. However, apt/dpkg cares not a whit for the *content* of that file. If you really wish, you can easily replace large doc files with tiny dummy files (at your own risk, of course).

```
sudo rm /path/to/file_name          // Warning: rm cannot be undone!
sudo touch /path/to/file_name
```

The 'du' command is very useful to determine if the space savings are worthwhile. Undo the substitution by reinstalling the package.