# Reduce the size of Ubuntu Installation on Arm Device

Tags: arm

Is it possible to reduce the size of Ubuntu Installation on Android Arm Device? I use Termux app for the installation of Ubuntu. I want to delete all unnecessary files such as documentation files because the space on the device is limited.

Comment: Have you tried the minimal installation oprton?

Answer (score 0):

This will be somewhat dependent on what non-standard toys you have installed including things like NVM and other "version managers" that can install multiple versions of a programming language, and whether you've installed suggested or only required packages for what you have installed.

[This related Question](https://askubuntu.com/q/129566/411468) and the top answer (from Andrew Ensley) tell how to use **dpkg** to prevent future installation of documentation, and how to remove existing docs. In the comments rubo77 mentions removing copyright files on a local machine, Jus12 notes that this can break things that use detection of the docs to recognize an existing installation such as VirtualBox, and Lissanro Rayen shared the realization to use `-print0` with **find** and `-0` with **xargs** as there may be things with spaces or newlines in their name.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/761303/411468) mentions

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```

This will remove packages that are not used and unnecessary archive files, including old Linux kernels in 16.04+, [and 11.10+ can use more complex directions in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/100953/411468).

A previous answer also mentions [BleachBit](https://github.com/bleachbit/bleachbit), which would be useful if you've already got Python 3 installed. A possible alternative is [uCareSystem-core](https://github.com/Utappia/uCareSystem), though IDK if both apps offer the same functionality.